# Algorithm to subtract numbers when result is negative

Tags: arithmetic

I am having a hard time to remember basic Math, in especial the subtract algorithm when the result will be negative. For example: `499 - 500 - 600` is `-601`, but how do I borrow  numbers and get to that result in the paper?

```
  499
  500
- 600
```

What I am doing is flipping the first two numbers:

```
  500
- 499
```

Which is `1`. I negate the result, `-1`, and after I just sum with the final number = `-601`.

Comment: Looks like a perfectly good algorithm. You'll probably want to be certain about the circumstances where you "flip the numbers ... and negate the result" and "sum with the final number", but what you did is correct.

Comment: In general it is true that $$\color{blue}a-\color{red}b=-(\color{red}b-\color{blue}a)$$. In your case $a=499$ and $b=500$

Comment: This also depends on what you're being taught. In a Common Core setting, they might have you break it into smaller pieces, noting that $499-500 = 499 - (499 + 1) = 499 - 499 - 1 = -1$, then subtracting $600$ from this would be the same as $-601$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you essentially wish to sum in column a list of signed numbers and that you already know how to calculate the difference of two positive numbers when the first is larger than the second and how to calculate the sum of multiple positive numbers. So for instance, here your problem would be to calculate $499+(-500)+(-600)$ and I would expect you to be able to calculate $500+600$ and $1100+(-499)=1100-499$. Then my advice is to proceed as follows:

1. if you are summing all positive numbers, do as always;
2. if you are summing all negative numbers, sum the absolute values and then put the minus sign;
3. if you are summing two numbers of different sign, determine the sign of the sum as the sign of the one of largest absolute value, then determine the absolute value of the sum as $$\text{(largest absolute value)}-\text{(smallest absolute value)}$$
4. if there are more than two numbers and at least one of each sign, then group all the positive numbers together and all the negative ones together, sum each of the groups with (1) and (2), then use (3) on the results.

This might not be the smartest and it certainly isn't the most stable procedure numerically. If you don't like it, summing the first two numbers with (1)-(3), and then the result with the third, then the result with the fourth et cetera is an option. I can see trying to do what essentially are sums and subtractions in column all at once being quite impractical, and I trust that if my country's Board of Education did not deem it worth teaching me as a child, it's because my instincts in that regard are correct.